# IF heat was the absence of cold, how would that change physics

Tags: thermodynamics, spacetime, time, universe

Back in high school, I had an argument with my physical science teacher. She said cold is the absence of heat. I asked why it couldn't be the other way around. She simply stated that was not possible. Being Native American, opposites define each other so in my language, heat is the absence of cold. If cold doesn't exist, then the word cold shouldn't exist. From my point of view (back then) if something was cold, it radiated cold. If something was hot, it radiated heat.

Recently I looked up the why of it and understand the logic but got me to wondering....what if heat was the absence of cold? If, in theory, parallel universes exist, what would that universe be like? If the arrow of time was reversed, would that be it? If heat could be trapped in a perfect container that let none of it out, like a black hole (minus hawking radiation)...I dunno, I'm not sure what that universe would be like.

Comment: Bob did a great job at explaining why the question is not well defined and can not be answered. The only part I could give a physical answer to is "if something was cold, it radiated cold. If something was hot, it radiated heat.", but it seems from your phrasing that you cleared that misconception already. Do you still need an answer on that part? (the rest, as written, is not answerable)

Answer (score 3):

> Back in high school, I had an argument with my physical science
> teacher. She said cold is the absence of heat.

She was wrong with respect to an understanding of thermodynamics.

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. The terms "hot" and "cold" are not thermodynamic definitions and do not reflect the presence or absence of heat because things do not "contain" heat. They refer to a persons reaction to the temperature of their skin resulting from the rate and duration of heat transfer from/to an object whose temperature is greater than or less than the temperature of their skin, respectively.

> Recently I looked up the why of it and understand the logic but got me
> to wondering....what if heat was the absence of cold?

Again, heat is neither the presence or the absence of cold. Something that is warm to the skin is something that is transferring heat to the skin raising the temperature of the skin, whereas something that is cool to the skin is something that is transferring heat away from the skin lowering the temperature of the skin.

The rest of your post simply reflects a misunderstanding of the concepts of hot, cold, heat, and temperature, as discussed above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer, it is difficult to answer questions like this since heat is a process and cold is a relative description and neither are “things” that you would meaningfully describe as present or absent. Given those difficulties in the question, this response explains the relevant concepts well +1

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you're saying.
But you didn't answer the question.
What if heat was the absence of cold?

Comment: Since you are asking to speculate what if the laws of physics didn't apply your question becomes off topic on this site, which states  "Questions about fictional physics 'Could a warp drive get you out of a black hole?' Questions about physics of fictional worlds which are not sufficiently grounded in real physics are off topic here, but they may be on topic at Science Fiction & Fantasy." Consequently I am voting to close your post.